# What's the correct way to redirect registry access when using NtOpenKey?

Tags: winapi, registry, 64-bit, 32-bit, wow64

The code I'm working on has both 32-bit and 64-bit components and they need to share information in the registry. Because of this, I'm trying to control registry redirection when using the `NtOpenKey` function (the user-mode equivalent of [`ZwOpenKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) - I need to call this function from 64-bit code but access the 32-bit registry. (The code used to be 32-bit only and now it's getting upgraded to 64-bit so I'd prefer using as much of the existing code as possible - this is to say I'd prefer not to rewrite everything to use `RegOpenKeyEx`.)

Naturally, `NtOpenKey` doesn't recognize the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` access flag, unlike high-level registry functions so there's no way to specify redirection.

At this point the only solution I can think of is to explicitly hardcode `Wow6432Node` in the key names when accessing the registry; something like:

`\Registry\Machine\Software\Wow6432Node\MyCompanyKey\MyKey`

Unfortunately, this is more of a hack and it's specifically discouraged by Microsoft.

Is there a correct solution to this problem? Reading through the documentation didn't help and I couldn't find any relevant search results either.

**Edit**: just a bit of extra detail: I need to support Windows Server 2003 32-bit/64-bit, Windows 7/8 and Windows Server 2008 32-bit/64-bit. (Basically all server flavors starting with Windows Server 2003 + Windows 7 and over.)

Comment: Are you sure that the native API has any support at all for redirection? If not, the answer is to use the high level Win32 API.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, I'm not sure at all - the documentation doesn't even mention it for the low-level API. I suspect there's no way to do that but then I wonder how other applications deal with this. The high-level registry API is fairly limited compared to kernel-level services. Plus I already have existing code that uses the low-level functions and it'd be a pain to rewrite all that. I'm trying with the hardcoded option for now although I really hate hacks like that.

Comment: It's not so hard to manage with the high level API. What is so limited about it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: lol, some people just enjoy calling kernel-mode routines (like me). =P (Also, one of these limitations is the inability to specify all those parameters in `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` using the Win32 API.)

Comment: @Mehrdad well, not me. :)  The main reason for it is embedded '\0' in key names for security purposes. This code is part of our licensing and it needs to work until we finally ditch it for a license server solution. This was working fine while the whole product was 32-bit only but now as we convert parts to 64-bit, issues are cropping up.

Comment: A thought. Does the old 32 bit code write to Wow6432Node? If so how?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan When the whole application was 32-bit, everything by default used the 32-bit registry. I'm looking through the code but I suspect right now we write to both registries, depending on which component does the writing - I know for a fact that some reads fail because a value is not found.

Comment: OK, but if you are using native API, then are you currently hard coding `Wow6432Node`? If not then clearly there is some redirection performed at the native level.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `Wow6432Node` is not hardcoded at the moment. The entire show worked fine when the application was 32-bit. Now with our transition to 64-bit code, we have problems - some keys are created in the 64-bit registry and some (the high-level ones using the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`) go to the 32-bit registry.

Comment: Can I just get this straight. If you use native API on a 64 bit system, in a 32 bit process, is there redirection to `WoW6432Node`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan All writes from a 32-bit process running on a 64-bit system go to the 32-bit registry - low-level and high-level calls. `Wow6432Node` is not hardcoded in the key names and the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flag is present for all high-level calls. Does that answer your question? If I run the same code built as 64-bit then the low-level calls go to the 64-bit registry.

Comment: Yes thanks. That was not what I was expecting though. So it looks like the redirector is implemented at the native API level.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think what happens is that the 32-bit hive is assigned to the process and that's why it works when everything is of the same bitness. Once I have mixed code, things break down. When I try to use the redirection flag for low-level calls, it's ignored, so 64-bit low-level calls still go to the 64-bit registry if I don't hardcode the `Wow6432Node` in the names. If I hardcode it, I get the 32-bit registry, as expected. Seems like a mess.

Comment: There isn't a 32 bit hive. The redirector is more fine grained than that. If I were you I would switch to the Win32 API. The ability to embed zeros isn't really a security feature. It's obscurity. If you want to secure keys, you can do that with the security API.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  NtOpenKey() should only be used from ring 0 code.  Where running on a 64-bit operating system is **not** a minor implementation detail.  Running drivers in 32-bit emulation mode is not an option at all.  Accordingly, NtOpenKey() doesn't pretend that it is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know and the plan is to drop what we have at the moment and switch to a 3rd-party licensing product. I still need to make this work in the meantime.

Comment: @HansPassant `NtOpenKey` can be called from user mode code just fine. While you're likely right in your reasoning, I wonder how a complex application with both 64-bit and 32-bit components is supposed to exchange registry information when parts of the application is a driver, for example. (Mine isn't.)

Comment: Make that double no sense.  A 64-bit process cannot possibly have a 32-bit component.  Or the other way around.  All code in a process **must** be the same bitness.

Comment: @xxbbcc: I would call it a bug in `NtOpenKey`. It it doesn't seem to be honoring the flag like it's supposed to. (WOW64 does it, so obviously it must have been intended -- assuming proper abstraction layers -- that `NtOpenKey` would be intended to honor the WOW64 flags.)

Comment: @HansPassant Of course it can. I can have several EXEs that need to share information in some way - some of them 32-bit and some of them 64-bit. Throw in a driver of any bitness that needs access to the same information and you have a problem. There are certainly workarounds (of various complexity) but the poorly designed registry in Windows cannot be used for this, although its purpose is to act as a centralized settings database.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just one comment on this solution being obscure: the feature I'm using is not a hack in that it's a documented feature of the OS and Microsoft used to use this same approach in the past for the same purpose. I agree with you that proper security would be way better but I've no time to go that way.

Comment: @HansPassant Just to clarify, I didn't say "a process could have mixed components". I said an application with multiple components, which is what I have - multiple EXEs and DLLs, some of which exist in both 32- and 64-bit versions and some that exist only in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native API does not offer an equivalent to `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`. Your options are:

1. Use the Win32 API.
2. Stick with native API and hard code the path.
3. Mix the Win32 and native APIs. Use the Win32 API to open `HKLM\Software` with `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`. Then call `NtQueryKey` to find out the native name of the key. And then use the native API from there on. This gets around your objection to hard coding.

Option 3 sounds plausible, but I've never called `NtQueryKey` and can't even be sure that the idea works.

Comment: There is also NtQueryObject, which is another function that can get the path. But I'm pretty sure NtQueryKey works.

Comment: Also be aware that there might be other keys that need redirection too.

Comment: @Mehrdad I suppose every time you open or create a key you could do the option 3 shuffle. But if it was me I'd go with option 1.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm accepting your answer although I haven't actually tried your suggestion - I simply went with the hacking hardcoding-the-names solution due of lack of time. Hopefully I can convince management to pay for a proper licensing product instead of rolling our own.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I misunderstood your problem -- I thought this flag as a key *option*, not an *access* specifier.
In that case, I believe `NtOpenKey` should work just fine with `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` as the access mask. What happens when you try that?

#### Old answer (wrong):

This is why Windows Vista & later introduced `NtOpenKeyEx`.

I recommend using `NtOpenKeyEx` if it's available (make sure to link dynamically, not statically), and if it isn't, then either use `NtCreateKey` if possible, or use `Wow6432Node` otherwise.

There's no other solution AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I didn't know about `NtOpenKeyEx` - I'll check it out. Unfortunately, I also need to support Windows Server 2003 R1 & R2 so I assume they won't have this function.

Comment: @xxbbcc: Yup. There's no good solution for pre-Vista -- the best one I can think of is to use `NtCreateKey`, then check to see if the `REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY` was set, and if not, then delete the key. It introduces an (unlikely) race condition but you don't have many options anyway.

Comment: I can't see how `NtOpenKeyEx` helps. Can you elaborate. How do we do the equivalent to `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Omg you're right -- I forgot `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` is an *access* mode; I thought it was a key *option* parameter... thanks so much for catching that.

Comment: @xxbbcc: I think I gave you the wrong answer -- you don't need `NtOpenKeyEx`; `NtOpenKey` should work just fine. Could you elaborate -- why doesn't `NtOpenKey` work? Why not just say `NtOpenKey(&hKey, access | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &oa)`?

Comment: @Mehrdad Lol, I was just wondering the same as I read the docs. :) To answer your comment, I haven't tried that yet, mainly because the docs are very specifically silent on that option. Let me see - I guess I could've tried this long ago but I'm afraid that even if it works, it may behave differently on different systems.

Comment: @xxbbcc: Okay, give it a try and see. It *should* work correctly... fingers crossed. :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that's what I thought so. I remember reading some articles some time back about the redirection flags not working. I'm going to give it a quick try anyway, it only takes a few minutes to build a new version.

Comment: @Mehrdad Using `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` with the low-level functions doesn't work - the flag is ignored and no error is returned. Registry keys are simply used as is, so unless `Wow6432Node` is part of the key name, keys go into the 64-bit registry.

Comment: @xxbbcc: That's weird, I guess it must be redirected at the Win32 level then. Go with David's answer maybe.

Comment: To add my 2 cents: the 32-bit version of `NtOpenKey` does in fact accept `KEY_WOW64_??KEY` constants in `DesiredAccess` parameter; passing `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` will get you through to the 64-bit registry. Here, the wow64 layer takes care of the redirection. However, in the 64-bit version, the redirection is done in `RegOpenKey` and `NtOpenKey` ignores `KEY_WOW64_??KEY` constants.