# SamDesired for NtOpenKey

Tags: c++, c, winapi, registry, ntdll

I have used `RegOpenKeyExW` from advapi.dll and there there is parameter samDesired I used this value `KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY`. Now I have to use ntdll.dll only so I am calling `NtOpenKeyEx` function.

How do I make a call that will allow me to open 64-bit registry? How is `samDesired` information  passed from `RegOpenKeyExW` to `NtOpenKeyEx`, since `NtOpenKey` is called from `RegOpenKeyExW`?

Comment: samDesired  passed exactly, without modifications.

Comment: Isn't that a dupe of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239049/whats-the-correct-way-to-redirect-registry-access-when-using-ntopenkey ?

Comment: @RbMm what parameter corresponds to samDesired?

Comment: ACCESS_MASK        DesiredAccess of course. @Jabberwocky - this is very easy can be checked

Comment: @Jabberwocky - however sorry, i mistake. `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` work for 32 bit apps - let open not redirected 64 bit key. but `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` not work for 64 bit apps - anyway 64bit key opened. your link was for `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`